# How to update config file value based on feature selected in MSI WIX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a MSI installer in which i want to update my application config value. There is no problem to update the value. The problem is the value will be conditional as explain below. I have three feature in installer as below:

```
    <Feature Id="Standalone" Title="Standalone" Level="2" Description="Standalone Deployment">
    </Feature>

     <Feature Id="SeplaAlone" Title="Seplalone" Level="2" Description="Standalone Deployment">

    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="RefaAlone" Title="ReflaAlone" Level="2" Description="Standalone Deployment">

    </Feature>
```

Here is my config file update code:

```
<util:XmlFile Id="UpdateOption" Action="setValue" File="$(var.erviceDir)\$(var.ServiceConfigFile)"
                      ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='Option'[\]]/@value"
                      SelectionLanguage="XPath" Permanent="yes" Value="[This is the value i want to set]"/>
```

User can only selected one feature at a time(implemented). Now what i want is if user selects standalone feature then value will be "0". If user selects seplaAlone feature then value will be "1" and if user selects the last one feature then value will be "2". I tried to do it but nothing worked. Also i define same variable with desired value in feature content but i does not work. How i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a custom Dialog with those features represented as Radio button selections. That custom dialog will set a property, say FEATURE_SELECTION (you can check wix documentation how to work with grouped radio buttons controls).

Then, the Value attribute for util:XmlFile will look like this Value="[FEATURE_SELECTION]"